# How can I make a WebView show only my URl and block all others URLs?

Tags: java, android, webview

my question is very simple , i have a webview that open "mywebsite.com"  but in my website there is some ads and popups so i want that the webview load just my url website and block the others like popups ... etc 
this is my webview code :

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    customViewContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.customViewContainer);
    webView = (VideoEnabledWebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

  //  mWebViewClient = new myWebViewClient();
   // webView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);

    mWebChromeClient = new myWebChromeClient();
    webView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
    //webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.OFF);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(false);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
    webView.loadUrl("http://aflamzone.com");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());


    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
```

please help me i need a solution for this , thank you all .

Answer (score 0):

You can do following:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view, final String url) {
                if (url.equals("http://aflamzone.com")) {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }

            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view, final WebResourceRequest request) {
                if (request.getUrl().toString().equals("http://aflamzone.com")) {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks , but the code not working for me ,the webview still show popups and ads